# How does one create a service account and set it as IAM user in CloudSQL with terraform

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp

Deploying a Postgres DB on cloudsql via terraform I want to have a service account as a user.

The documentation examples only show individual users.  Following that example using email address, I get repeated error messages about the name being too long or email address invalid/wrong pattern.

```
    resource "google_sql_database_instance" "master" {
      project             = var.project
      deletion_protection = false
      name                = "demo"
      database_version    = "POSTGRES_14"
    
      settings {
        tier = "db-f1-micro"
    
        database_flags {
          name  = "cloudsql.iam_authentication"
          value = "on"
        }
      }
    }
    
    resource "google_sql_user" "iam_user" {
      name     = "codeangler@example.com"
      instance = google_sql_database_instance.master.name
      type     = "CLOUD_IAM_USER"
    }
    
    resource "google_sql_user" "iam_sa_user" {
      name     = google_service_account.custom_cloudsql_sa.name
      instance = google_sql_database_instance.master.name
      type     = "CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"
    }
    
    resource "google_project_iam_member" "iam_user_cloudsql_instance_user" {
      project = var.project
      role    = "roles/cloudsql.instanceUser"
      member  = format("user:%s", google_sql_user.iam_user.name)
    }
    
    
    resource "google_service_account" "custom_cloudsql_sa" {
      account_id = var.project
    }
    
    resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "impersonation_sa" {
      service_account_id = google_service_account.custom_cloudsql_sa.name
      role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountUser"
      member             = format("user:%s", google_sql_user.iam_user.name)
    }
```

error message

> Error: Error, failed to insert user yetanothercaseyproject-c268@yetanothercaseyproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com into instance demo: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid request: User name "yetanothercodeanglerproject-c268@yetanothercodeanglerproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com" to be created is too long (max 63).., invalid

> │   with google_sql_user.iam_sa_user,
> │   on main.tf line 60, in resource "google_sql_user" "iam_sa_user":
> │   60: resource "google_sql_user" "iam_sa_user" {
> │

or changing the recourse to use email give new error

```
    resource "google_sql_user" "iam_sa_user" {
      name     = google_service_account.custom_cloudsql_sa.email
      instance = google_sql_database_instance.master.name
      type     = "CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"
    }
```

> Error: Error, failed to insert user aixjyznd@yetanothercodeanglerproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com into instance demo: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid request: Database username for Cloud IAM service account should be created without ".gserviceaccount.com" suffix., invalid

Answer (score 1):

use  the key **account_id** and not *name* nor *email*

```
    resource "google_sql_user" "iam_sa_user" {
      name     = google_service_account.custom_cloudsql_sa.account_id
      instance = google_sql_database_instance.master.name
      type     = "CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Add an IAM user or service account to the database](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/add-manage-iam-users#creating-a-database-user) and my experience you should omit the `.gserviceaccount.com` suffix in the account email.

Sample code:

```
resource "google_sql_user" "iam_sa_user" {
      name     = replace(google_service_account.custom_cloudsql_sa.email, ".gserviceaccount.com", "") // "sa-test-account-01@prj-test-stg.iam"
      instance = google_sql_database_instance.master.name
      type     = "CLOUD_IAM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT"
}
```